# Failed to create HTML page using GWT plugin for Eclipse

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

When i create a new GWT (version 2.3) project using the Eclipse (version 3.5) plugin, without enabling sample code, i failed to create a new HTML page by using the GWT->new HTML page. It opens the dialog window, i enter the name of the file and the module, but when i press 'finish', it does nothing! Bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is gwt eclipse plugin bug.. Here is the exception ;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.ResourceUtils.getResourceAsString(ResourceUtils.java:655)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.ResourceUtils.getResourceAsString(ResourceUtils.java:467)
at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewHostPageWizard.getDocType(NewHostPageWizard.java:216)
at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewHostPageWizard.getInitialContents(NewHostPageWizard.java:148)
```

See bug [#6338](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6338)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the \war folder of your project, html files are put there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.

Temporary Solution:
Just create GWT Project with sample contents. than you can see html file in war.
Copy that into your project. Modify it. (It's easy to inspect)